# VBA Script to loop through entire row and Bold the cell if specific substring is found

Tags: vba, excel

How do i loop through an entire row say "A" till the row containing the last entry and search for the following substring in the cell "FG-DFG-123" ? 
Once i find that the substring is present, i need to Bold the entire cell.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There are many solutions already present on the web you just need to search

Comment: What have you tried so far? While you will find help to specific problems here, this isn't a code writing service. Provide some effort on your own!

Comment: You can simply use conditional formatting to do this. You no need VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use conditional format.

[image]

Comment: Thanks harun24hr. But i would want it as a VBA Script.

Comment: Thanks guys ! I got the piece of code working fine.                            Sub Format_Boldheadings()

Dim StartCell As Range
Set StartCell = Range("A1")
Dim myList As Range
Set myList = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Dim x As Range
    For Each x In myList
    'myList.ClearFormats
    x.Font.Bold = False
         If InStr(1, x.Text, "FG-DFG-123") > 0 Or InStr(1, x.Text, "FG-GHT-123") > 0 Then
                x.Font.Bold = True
                Else
                x.Font.Bold = False
          End If
    Next
End Sub

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys. This piece of script is working fine.

```
Sub Format_Boldheadings()

    Dim StartCell As Range
    Set StartCell = Range("A1")
    Dim myList As Range

    Set myList = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Dim x As Range

    For Each x In myList
        'myList.ClearFormats
        x.Font.Bold = False
        If InStr(1, x.Text, "DFG") > 0 Or InStr(1, x.Text, "RTY") > 0 Then
            x.Font.Bold = True
        Else
            x.Font.Bold = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```